# Erro com criação de janela usando tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

esse é o codigo que estou tentando rodar:

```
from tkinter import *
janela = Tk()
janela.mainloop()
janela.geometry(450x450)
janela.title('calculadora GUI')
```

Ele abria a janela normalmente antes de eu adicionar `janela.geometry(450x450)` mas ignorava `janela.title('calculadora GUI')` abrindo a janela com nome de tk, agora ele nem abre, da "erro de syntax" e destaca '450x'.

Problema basiquinho, mas eu sou bem iniciante mesmo... agradeço dês de já

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro ocorre por duas causas.

- Você está chamando o `mainloop` no começo, impedindo o código de executar o resto, assim ele não altera o título e nem o tamanho
- A *função* `geometry()` recebe como parâmetro uma `string` e você está passando um número.

Para corrigir isso:

```py
from tkinter import *
janela = Tk()
janela.title('calculadora GUI')
janela.geometry('450x450')//tanto faz se será o geometry ou o title primeiro
janela.mainloop()//deve ser o último a ser chamado
```